# cannot unlock Hitachi hard drive lock, after removing BIOS-user which created the password

Tags: hard-drive, passwords, sata

I created a BIOS-user on an HP Pro laptop, then with this user I created a hard drive lock on my Hitachi HDD 7K500-320. Afterwards I deleted the BIOS-user (hoping that it will remove the hard drive lock as well) which resulted in me being unable to unlock said hard drive ever since.

I have contacted both HP and Hitachi and both said that they cannot do anything ("not our hardware" and "lock was not created by our software"). How can I unlock my HDD? Preferably in a way which does not format the entire HDD?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I would be able to unlock the hard drive with its master password and using `hdparm` under Linux. Problem is that the master password is not 32 times `space` in my case...